# How to randomly choose and apply an op from a list of ops in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

For data augmentation purposes I want to have n different transformations to the data and want to randomly choose and apply one of them for each image in a batch. Something like:

```
image = tf.apply_random_op(image, [op1, op2, op3])
images, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image, label])
```

Is that possible?

Obs: I want the op to be chosen randomly while the session is being executed.

Comment: Have you considered generating a random integer and using if-else statements?

Comment: This won't satisfy my last observation, because it won't be made in a symbolic manner.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your last observation? I'm sorry but I'm not getting it.

Comment: Tensorflow builds a symbolic graph. Vanilla if-else statement is not symbolic. But I found tf.cond that is a symbolic version of if-else. I posted a solution based on tf.cond.

Comment: perhaps `tf.case` might be a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

I think I came up with a solution:

```
def apply_random_op(tensor, ops):
  n = len(ops)
  rand_idx = tf.floor(tf.random_uniform([], 0, n, dtype=tf.float32))
  op_idx = tf.constant(0.0, dtype=tf.float32)
  chain = tf.cond(tf.equal(op_idx, rand_idx), lambda: ops[0](tensor), lambda: ops[1](tensor))
  for i in xrange(2, n):
    op_idx = tf.constant(float(i), dtype=tf.float32)
    chain = tf.cond(tf.equal(op_idx, rand_idx), lambda: ops[i](tensor), lambda: chain)
  return chain
```